# The cohomology of the surface bundle over $S^1\vee S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fiber-bundles, mayer-vietoris-sequence

Given a surface bundle $S_g\to E \xrightarrow{f} S^1\vee S^1$, where $S_g$ is a closed surface of genus $g$. I want to calculate $H^3(E)$ by applying Mayer-Vietoris. Name the two circles of $S^1\vee S^1$ by $A$ and $B$ and define $U:=f^{-1}(A), V:=f^{-1}(A)$, which are $S_g$-bundles over $S^1$. Note $U\cap V\cong S_g$, thus by Mayer-Vietoris we have

$...\to H^2(U)\oplus H^2(V)\to H^2(S_g)=\mathbb Z\to H^3(E)\to H^3(U)\oplus H^3(V)=\mathbb Z^2\to H^3(U\cap V)\cong H^3(S_g)=1$

Now if $H^2(U)\oplus H^2(V)\to H^2(S_g)=\mathbb Z$ is trivial, then $H^3(E)=\mathbb Z^3$;
if $H^2(U)\oplus H^2(V)\to H^2(S_g)=\mathbb Z$ is surjective, then $H^3(E)=\mathbb Z^2$.

I am not sure if the rank of $H^3(E)$ depends or it is always a constant?

Comment: Are the bundles $U$ and $V$ orientable $S_g$-bundles over $S^1$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I am mainly considering about the oriented surface bundles, thus as subbundles of an oriented surface bundle, I think they should be also oriented. Do you have a result for the oriented case?

Comment: For an orientable bundle $F \to M \to S^1$ where $F$ has dimension $n-1$, inclusion of the fiber induces a surjection $H^{n-1}(M) \to H^{n-1}(F)$. This follows from the cohomological version of $(\ast)$ in Example 2.48 of Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATplain.pdf) for example, although you can prove it in other ways. In the non-orientable case, the claim is not true. For example, the Klein bottle $K$ is a non-orientable $S^1$-bundle over $S^1$, and inclusion of a fiber induces the zero map $H^1(K) \to H^1(S^1)$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese sorry, I can't see how to apply $H^{n-1}(M)\to H^{n-1}(F)$ to the Mayer-Vietoris in my calculation. Indeed, I don't have this map.

Comment: It's a separate application of Mayer-Vietoris. I will write an answer when I have time.